# Как сделать автообновление таймера при обновлении страницы?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! 
Нашел в интернете таймер. Меня он в принципе устраивает, но он останавливается, когда время на таймере заканчивается. 
Как можно сделать так, чтобы таймер автоматически обновлялся при обновлении страницы ?

Или было бы шикарно, если по истечении времени, генерировалась новая дата на сутки, и он перезапускался автоматически.

*Благодарю!*

**Вот скрипт таймера**

```js
year = 2018; month = 1; day = 21; hour= 24; minute= 0; sec= 0;

function CountBox() {
  dateNow = new Date;
  amount = dateFuture.getTime() - dateNow.getTime() + 5;
  delete dateNow;
  if (amount < 0) {
    out = "<div class='countbox-num'><div class='countbox-days1'><span></span>0</div><div class='countbox-days2'><span></span>0</div><div class='countbox-days-text'></div></div>" +
    "<div class='countbox-space'></div>" +
    "<div class='countbox-num'><div class='countbox-hours1'><span></span>0</div><div class='countbox-hours2'><span></span>0</div><div class='countbox-hours-text'></div></div>" +
    "<div class='countbox-space'></div>" +
    "<div class='countbox-num'><div class='countbox-mins1'><span></span>0</div><div class='countbox-mins2'><span></span>0</div><div class='countbox-mins-text'></div></div>" +
    "<div class='countbox-space'></div>" +
    "<div class='countbox-num'><div class='countbox-secs1'><span></span>0</div><div class='countbox-secs2'><span></span>0</div><div class='countbox-secs-text'></div></div>";
    document.getElementById("countbox1").innerHTML = out
    document.getElementById("countbox2").innerHTML = out
    document.getElementById("countbox3").innerHTML = out
  } else {
    days = 0;
    days1 = 0;
    days2 = 0;
    hours = 0;
    hours1 = 0;
    hours2 = 0;
    mins = 0;
    mins1 = 0;
    mins2 = 0;
    secs = 0;
    secs1 = 0;
    secs2 = 0;
    out = "";
    amount = Math.floor(amount / 1e3);
    days = Math.floor(amount / 86400);
    days1 = (days >= 10) ? days.toString().charAt(0) : '0';
    days2 = (days >= 10) ? days.toString().charAt(1) : days.toString().charAt(0);
    amount = amount % 86400;
    hours = Math.floor(amount / 3600);
    hours1 = (hours >= 10) ? hours.toString().charAt(0) : '0';
    hours2 = (hours >= 10) ? hours.toString().charAt(1) : hours.toString().charAt(0);
    amount = amount % 3600;
    mins = Math.floor(amount / 60);
    mins1 = (mins >= 10) ? mins.toString().charAt(0) : '0';
    mins2 = (mins >= 10) ? mins.toString().charAt(1) : mins.toString().charAt(0);
    amount = amount % 60;
    secs = Math.floor(amount);
    secs1 = (secs >= 10) ? secs.toString().charAt(0) : '0';
    secs2 = (secs >= 10) ? secs.toString().charAt(1) : secs.toString().charAt(0);
    out = "<div class='countbox-num'><div class='countbox-days1'><span></span>" + days1 + "</div><div class='countbox-days2'><span></span>" + days2 + "</div><div class='countbox-days-text'></div></div>" +
    "<div class='countbox-space'></div>" +
    "<div class='countbox-num'><div class='countbox-hours1'><span></span>" + hours1 + "</div><div class='countbox-hours2'><span></span>" + hours2 + "</div><div class='countbox-hours-text'></div></div>" +
    "<div class='countbox-space'></div>" +
    "<div class='countbox-num'><div class='countbox-mins1'><span></span>" + mins1 + "</div><div class='countbox-mins2'><span></span>" + mins2 + "</div><div class='countbox-mins-text'></div></div>" +
    "<div class='countbox-space'></div>" +
    "<div class='countbox-num'><div class='countbox-secs1'><span></span>" + secs1 + "</div><div class='countbox-secs2'><span></span>" + secs2 + "</div><div class='countbox-secs-text'></div></div>";
    $(".countbox").html(out);
    setTimeout("CountBox()", 1e3)
  }
}
month = --month;
dateFuture = new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, sec);
window.onload = function () {
  CountBox()
}
```

Comment: а что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: У меня не получается сделать так, чтобы при обновлении страницы, таймер стартовал каждый раз сначала. 
В интернете всё облазил, и не нашёл решения. Поэтому решил заглянуть сюда.

Comment: Рекомендую начать изучать JavaScript, тогда такие задачи будет возможность решать самостоятельно.

Comment: я для tampermonkey использовал такой скрипт, для автообновления страницы: 
`setInterval(function fresh() {
    location.reload();
} , 1000 * 60 * 2);`